# Mysql erro ambiguous

Tags: mysql, select

estou com um erro em meu Select

```
SELECT *,
SUM(IF(debito_credito_financeiro = 'D', valor_financeiro, 0)) AS debito,
SUM(IF(debito_credito_financeiro = 'C', valor_financeiro, 0)) AS credito,
(SELECT SUM(IF(debito_credito_financeiro = 'C', valor_financeiro, -valor_financeiro)) FROM cad_financeiro AS L2 WHERE cad_financeiro.id_financeiro >= L2.id_financeiro) AS saldo
FROM cad_financeiro
JOIN cad_trabalho ON cad_financeiro.id_trabalho = cad_trabalho.id_trabalho
JOIN cad_paciente ON cad_trabalho.id_paciente = cad_paciente.id_paciente
JOIN cad_cliente ON cad_paciente.id_cliente = cad_cliente.id_cliente
WHERE id_cliente = '8'
GROUP BY id_cliente, id_financeiro ORDER BY id_financeiro
```

ela gera erro, mas quando removo a linha

```
JOIN cad_cliente ON cad_paciente.id_cliente = cad_cliente.id_cliente
```

ela funciona perfeitamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque tens o `WHERE id_cliente = '8'`, tens de colocar `WHERE cad_cliente.id_cliente = '8'`.

Pois ele faz confusão e não sabe a qual te estás a referir

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo, muito obrigado

Comment: Aprove a resposta dele ^^

Comment: e que tinha que esperar 8 minutos :)